state is not defined in browser page
enter image description here# On my sign in page it says state is not defined there is not error showing in the error i have uploaded my signin.jsx .Thanks for any help

Tried to access console in browser,vs code but not showing where it is coming .i was trying to develop a mern web app . But this is the error that got stuck and i donot know where it is  coming
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signInStart, signInSuccess, signInFailure } from '../redux/user/userSlice';
import { Alert, Button, Label, Spinner, TextInput } from 'flowbite-react'; // Assuming these components are correctly imported
import OAuth from '../components/OAuth';

export default function SignIn() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const { loading, error: errorMessage } = useSelector(state => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value.trim() });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!formData.email || !formData.password) {
      return dispatch(signInFailure('Please fill all the fields'));
    }
    try {
      dispatch(signInStart());
      const res = await fetch('/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      if (res.ok) {
        dispatch(signInSuccess(data));
        navigate('/');
      } else {
        dispatch(signInFailure(data.message || 'Sign in failed'));
      }
    } catch (er`import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signInStart, signInSuccess, signInFailure } from '../redux/user/userSlice';
import { Alert, Button, Label, Spinner, TextInput } from 'flowbite-react'; // Assuming these components are correctly imported
import OAuth from '../components/OAuth';

export default function SignIn() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const { loading, error: errorMessage } = useSelector(state => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value.trim() });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!formData.email || !formData.password) {
      return dispatch(signInFailure('Please fill all the fields'));
    }
    try {
      dispatch(signInStart());
      const res = aror) {
      dispatch(signInFailure(error.message));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen mt-20'>
      <div className='flex p-3 max-w-3xl mx-auto flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center gap-5'>
        {/* left */}
        <div className='flex-1'>
          <Link to='/' className='font-bold dark:text-white text-4xl'>
            <span className='px-2 py-1 bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 rounded-lg text-white'>
              Sahand's
            </span>
            Blog
          </Link>
          <p className='text-sm mt-5'>
            This is a demo project. You can sign in with your email and password
            or with Google.
          </p>
        </div>
        {/* right */}
        <div className='flex-1'>
          <form className='flex flex-col gap-4' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <Label value='Your email' />
              <TextInput
                type='email'
                placeholder='name@company.com'
                id='email'
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Label value='Your password' />
              <TextInput
                type='password'
                placeholder='**********'
                id='password'
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <Button gradientDuoTone='purpleToPink' type='submit' disabled={loading}>
              {loading ? (
                <>
                  <Spinner size='sm' />
                  <span className='pl-3'>Loading...</span>
                </>
              ) : (
                'Sign In'
              )}
            </Button>
            <OAuth />
          </form>
          <div className='flex gap-2 text-sm mt-5'>
            <span>Dont Have an account?</span>
            <Link to='/sign-up' className='text-blue-500'>
              Sign Up
            </Link>
          </div>
          {errorMessage && (
            <Alert className='mt-5' color='failure'>
              {errorMessage}
            </Alert>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

